What is the best practise of handling images in react?
I've been working on a project which has lots of images to display. I found that loading all the images takes a lot of time. A friend suggested that I use a cache to save time.
So, I converted the images into String of Base64 and when I log in to the website, I store all the necessary images in the cache and load them. However, I'm not sure whether it's good practice or not.
Below is the code I tried.
I hope to hear opinions from the seniors.
export const imageUrlToBase64 = async (file, fileType, callback) => {

    console.log(file);
    if(file instanceof Blob) {
        imageFileToBase64(file, fileType, function(base64String) {
            if(base64String) {
                callback(base64String);
            }
        });
    } else {
        urlToBase64(file, fileType, function(base64String) {
            if(base64String) {
                callback(base64String);
            }
        });
    }
    // Create a new Image element
    
}

export const saveToCache = async (url, data) => {
  if (url === 'user') console.log(data);

  try {
    const cache = await caches.open('mychache');
    await cache.put(url, new Response(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error saving data to cache:', error);
  }
};


export const readFromCache = async (url) => {
  
  let data = "";
  
  try {
    const cache = await caches.open('mychache');
    const response = await cache.match(url);
    if (response) {
      data = await response.text();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error reading from cache:', error);
  }
  if(url === 'user') console.log(data)
  return data;
};



You could add loading="lazy" to your img tag. https://web.dev/articles/browser-level-image-lazy-loading
